# Supermicro server not detecting SAS drives

Tags: sas, sata, supermicro

I got a used Supermicro server with no drives in it. When I plug in a SATA drive it detects it just fine but when I plug in a SAS drive, even the BIOS will not detect the drive. It looks like the backplane has SAS connectors on it, but I'm not sure if the motherboard supports it, or if there is some sort of configuration needed to enable it. I've reset the CMOS to see if that helped but it did not.

Here is the output of `dmidecode` on the machine
https://gist.github.com/MassTroy/126eb1cb78858ca495301a300e6c79f4

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 2.1a      
    Release Date: 12/30/2011

Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Supermicro
    Product Name: X8DTL
    Serial Number: VM2AS37615
```

Looking up that model number I find 6 different sub models but none of them just say `X8DTL`

Comment: This BIOS won't  detect the drives. If your model has an active SAS controller, it will appear during system startup and offer you do configure drives. According to your output, you have an SCSI controller (SAS = Serial Attached SCSI), but it's deactivated. Check the manual to learn if/how you can activate it (if it is indeed present and possible to activate it) - might be even a jumper.

Comment: Look for model label `X8DTL` on motherboard. Also find model of backplane and cable between them.

Comment: It looks like I have `X8DTL-iF` motherboard and `SAS815TQ` backplane. It looks like the motherboard doesn't support SAS despite the backplane supporting it. Based on the table at the bottom of page 10 of this https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/5500/MNL-1076.pdf